# How can you try to spawn a pre-tamed cat with or without commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to spawn a pre-tamed black cat and name it "Suki I" and have a black baby cat named "Suki II". How do you do said action without spawn eggs?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I think maybe I'll use '/spawn ocelot' twice then tame 'n' name 'em.

Comment: The other question's answer doesn't fully answer this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command for the adult cat:

```
/summon ocelot ~ ~ ~ {Owner:MCAydenBird,CatType:1,CustomName:"Suki I"}
```

Command for the baby cat:

```
/summon ocelot ~ ~ ~ {Owner:MCAydenBird,CatType:1,CustomName:"Suki II",Age:-72000}
```

The baby cat will stay a baby for 72,000 ticks or about an hour.  You can input much longer durations.  As an example, I tried -2000000000.  The command succeeds and it produces a kitten.  The math on that would work out to over 3 years if 20 ticks was exactly a second.

Here is the [ocelot data values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocelot#Data_values) on the wiki if you want to mess with tags a little more.

---

Edit:  Response to the comment.

From the ocelot data values wiki link in the answer above:

> CatType: The ID of the skin the ocelot has. 0 = wild ocelot, 1 = tuxedo, 2 = tabby, 3 = siamese.

Comment: Could you post a list of CatTypes so I can differentiate. Plus, I am simple. I guess I'd have to have half the screen to MC and half to Arqade so I can input it, but still, THANKS

Comment: Can you make one that says the parent of Suki 2 is Suki 1?

Comment: I edited the answer to include cat types.  You can copy and paste the commands.  To paste into Minecraft use Ctrl+V.  To the second comment, can you clarify?  Do you want the name to be "Parent of Suki 2 is Suki 1?"

Comment: It's not working, even though I changed the username 4 my W10 MCBTU Xbox user.

Comment: The command given is for Java Edition.  Are you attempting to use it with xbox?

Comment: Yes, I lost MCJE via wiping my PC and cannot reinstall it.